# How do I schedule a method to run after a delay

Tags: iphone, ios

I want to be able to setup a timer to count for 23 seconds then perform a function. How could I do this? Would I need NSTimer?

Comment: Have you read the docs for NSTimer and tried using it ?

Comment: You can use `[self performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:]`

Comment: These days, with modern compilers and blocks, I'd just use `dispatch_after`. No need to write a separate callback function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:23.0 target:self selector:@selector(myThingToDo) options:nil];
```

<sub>Typed on mobile, test first.</sub>

Also, there's a [neat category](https://github.com/jivadevoe/NSTimer-Blocks) available that allows you to use NSTimer with Blocks!

Comment: I recently stumbled upon a neat category on `NSTimer` to use `NSTimer` in conjunction with blocks (https://github.com/jivadevoe/NSTimer-Blocks).

Comment: Or https://github.com/Abizern/NSTimer-JCSBlocks which also lets you schedule a repeatable timer, or an interruptible one.

Answer (score 1):

You could use GCD methods directly, which saves having to write a separate callback function:

```
// Just for clarity I'm defining the time period separately, 23 seconds from now.
dispatch_time_t delay = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 23 * NSEC_PER_SEC);

dispatch_after(delay, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    // Anything in here will be run on the main queue 23 seconds from now.
});
```